# Objective-C - Determining IP address of iPod touch programmatically

Tags: objective-c, ip, ip-address, multicast, multicastsocket

I'm programming in objective-C for several iPod devices and I was wondering about something. I'm developing an application that utilizes the server-client model and I'm using the UDP protocol with C sockets. Is there a class out there that allows me to determine the iPod devices IP address? After googling around other forums, I haven't found anything. Obviously this command wouldn't work, but something like ipAddress = self.ip is what I had in mind. I'm setting up multicast C sockets and I'm trying to do a workaround that resembles the ping command, which obviously doesn't exist in objective-C either or to my knowledge (which is limited, as I've only been programming in objective-C since the start of this summer) at least. Any advice or tips?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This snippet of code will retrieve it by looping through the interfaces.

```
- (NSString *)getIPAddress 
{
    NSString *address = @"error";
    struct ifaddrs *interfaces = NULL;
    struct ifaddrs *temp_addr = NULL;
    int success = 0;

    // retrieve the current interfaces - returns 0 on success
    success = getifaddrs(&interfaces);
    if (success == 0)  
    {
        // Loop through linked list of interfaces
        temp_addr = interfaces;
        while(temp_addr != NULL)  
        {
            if(temp_addr->ifa_addr->sa_family == AF_INET)
            {
                // Check if interface is en0 which is the wifi connection on the iPhone  
                if([[NSString stringWithUTF8String:temp_addr->ifa_name] isEqualToString:@"en0"])  
                {
                    // Get NSString from C String
                    address = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:inet_ntoa(((struct sockaddr_in *)temp_addr->ifa_addr)->sin_addr)];
                }
            }
            temp_addr = temp_addr->ifa_next;
        }
    }

    // Free memory
    freeifaddrs(interfaces); 
    return address; 
}
```

Comment: First test and run the code , then post the full code.

i am getting warings and error from the above code.

warning: implicit declaration of function 'getifadrs'
error: dereferencing pointter to incomplete type for (temp_addr != NULL)
and few more errors.

Comment: You didn't include the proper headers. First understand the code before copying and pasting it off the bathroom wall.

Comment: Anyone want to give us some incite on what the proper headers are?

Comment: @TaylorAddison
`#import <netinet/in.h>
#import <ifaddrs.h>
#import <sys/socket.h>`
@BenLakey Thanks for your solution

Answer (score 0):

Did you see this?  http://www.appsamuck.com/day4.html.  I think the right answer is to use `CFHost` in the SDK.

**EDIT**
It appears the source in that project is using the following code, **which makes it a completely invalid solution** unless Apple decides to put `NSHost` into the SDK.

```
-(NSString*)getAddress {  
    char iphone_ip[255];  
    strcpy(iphone_ip,"127.0.0.1"); // if everything fails  
    NSHost* myhost =[NSHost currentHost];  
    if (myhost)  
    {  
        NSString *ad = [myhost address];  
        if (ad)  
            strcpy(iphone_ip,[ad cStringUsingEncoding: NSISOLatin1StringEncoding]);  
    }  
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",iphone_ip];   
}
```

Comment: This is the first thing that popped into my head, as well

Comment: NSHost is not supported by the iPhone SDK. It would be great if it were though.

Comment: NSHost is supported by the iPhone SDK!

Comment: No, it is not. See Apple’s Technical Q&A QA1652 for proof. NSHost is private.